# Parsley Custom Remote Validation with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, parsley.js

I had trouble implementing parsley.remote.js because of AMD in our require configuration.

I'm trying to implement a custom validator that does an AJAX request and returns true or false based on the response.

Problem is, I keep getting a response of false regardless of what the AJAX request returns.

Why does this code never work?

```js
window.ParsleyValidator.addValidator('cardcode', 
    function (value) {
        var valid = false;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/data/checkout/cvvCheck.json',
            data: {
                cvv: value
            },
            success: function(response) {
                if(response.valid === true) {
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    }, 32);
```

```html
<input type="tel" name="card-code" id="card-code" maxlength="4" required="" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-required-message="Please enter the cvv" data-parsley-type="number" data-parsley-type-message="Please enter a valid cvv" data-parsley-cardcode="true" data-parsley-cardcode-message="Please ensure you are entering the correct cvv." data-parsley-id="65">
```

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that the AJAX call to your remote validator is being made asynchronously and that means that your response is coming back too late for Parsley, so it will always assume a false result for the validation.

While synchronous AJAX calls should be [avoided](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11013), if you add the **async: false** option to your AJAX call your code should work:

```
window.ParsleyValidator.addValidator('cardcode', 
    function (value) {
        var valid = false;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/data/checkout/cvvCheck.json',
            data: {
                cvv: value
            },
            async: false,
            success: function(response) {
                if(response.valid === true) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    }, 32);
```

Here's an asynchronous method that I found that worked for me - you'll need to load [parsley.remote.min.js](http://parsleyjs.org/dist/parsley.remote.min.js) instead of parsley.min.js, then setup a custom remote validator using this code:

```
window.Parsley.addAsyncValidator('cardcode', function (xhr) {
    var response = xhr.responseText;
    if (response.valid === true) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}, '/data/checkout/cvvCheck.json');
```

Comment: @GeorgeInngs Your answer was flagged as "very low quality" by a user. I happened to review that vote and, at the time, your answer consisted of http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/32934394/1 which was emphatically not an answer to the question. Hence I voted to delete the answer as "not an answer", which automatically added the "This does not really answer the question" comment. Since then, you have edited your answer to the point that it is definitely a useful, comprehensive answer - **thank you for that**. As a result, I have upvoted your answer and removed my original comment.